# storing sortable item order on a database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jquery-ui, database-design, database

I'm attempting to create a form layout that allows the user to place the forms in whatever order they desire. For this, I'm using the jQuery UI Sortable plugin which allows me to retrieve the 'order number' of each DOM element in the list. The problem is that I want to persist this information in a database so that I can later re-render the forms in the order specified by the user.

Currently, the forms are generated based upon the model provided. Say I have a model like this:

```
var model = {
title : 'Goldfinger',
actor : 'Sean Connery', 
genre : 'Action'
}
```

For this model (I'm using Mongodb), three input boxes are generated for the respective key-value pairing, and are displayed in the order title -> actor -> genre. What is the best way to store the sort-order information for each field in this model?

The only thing I've come up with is doing nested objects with a 'position' attribute.

```
var model = {
title : { value : Goldfinger, position : 0 },
actor : { value : Sean Connery, position : 2 },
genre : { value : Action, position: 1 }
}
```

But this seems cumbersome to me, and complicates both the construction of the schema and later queries in the database. Does anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: does the user also have the ability to add new fields? Is each form unique, or there are a few premade forms?

Comment: The user has the ability to add new fields, but only fields of a select type. For example, the user could add multiple 'actor' fields which would then be saved to an array in Mongo.

Comment: Then I'd probably save position as you proposed.